# Mixing colours in OpenGL GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to create a translucent , stained glass effect in OpenGL, using C++.

I use a normal map generated from a perlin noise texture. Refraction is calculated with respect to manipulated normal vectors and it works.
For stained glass, I am trying mixing the colour from skybox through refraction, with another colour. I tried this with a constant value, and that works too.
When I try to get the second colour from a texture, I do not see the object on screen. I can load the texture if i ignore refraction and mixing though.
here is my vertex shader :

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 aTangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 aBitangent;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 tangentLightPos;
out vec3 tangentViewPos;
out vec3 tangentFragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

//normal
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

void main()
{
    texCoord = aTexCoord;
    FragPos = vec3(view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));

    mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(model)));
    vec3 T = normalize(normalMatrix * aTangent);
    vec3 N = normalize(normalMatrix * aNormal);
    T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N);
    vec3 B = cross(N, T);
    mat3 TBN = transpose(mat3(T, B, N));  

    tangentLightPos = TBN * lightPos;
    tangentViewPos = TBN * viewPos;
    tangentFragPos = TBN * FragPos;

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

and my fragment shader :

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec2 texCoord;
in vec3 tangentLightPos;
in vec3 tangentViewPos;
in vec3 tangentFragPos;

uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;
uniform samplerCube skybox;

uniform vec3 cameraPos;

void main()
{
    //normal map - normal
    vec3 normalDir = texture(texture2, texCoord).rgb;
    normalDir = normalize(normalDir * 2.0 - 1.0);

    vec3 Incident = normalize(tangentFragPos - cameraPos);
    vec3 RefractedDir = refract(Incident, normalDir, 1.0/1.2);

    float DispersionIndex = 1.0 - dot(Incident, normalDir);
    vec3 RefractedFragColor = vec3(texture(skybox, RefractedDir).rgb);
 
    //FIXME:
    vec3 texColor = texture(texture1, texCoord).rgb;
    vec3 constTexColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 
    FragColor = mix( vec4(RefractedFragColor, 1.0), vec4(texColor.rgb, 0.5), 0.2); // doesnt show object on screen
    // FragColor = mix( vec4(RefractedFragColor, 1.0), vec4(constTexColor.rgb, 0.5), 0.2); --> works , shows a tint on glass
    // FragColor = vec4(texColor, 1.0); ---> shows only texture
}
```

with constant value for color in mix :
[image]

with only texture:
[image]

Why does the mix not work with color from texture?

Comment: what if you mix with the texture colour with 1.0 alpha instead of 0.5?

Comment: it does not work.  I have tried different alpha values with a constant `texColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` and that works everytime. changing value of alpha with `texColor = texture(texture1, texCoord).rgb;` does not give any result.

Comment: How do you bind the textures and set the uniforms? I wonder if you are getting different sampler uniform locations because in the texture-only test, the skybox and texture2 are unused and are likely to be optimized out. If your code uses the wrong locations, it might coincidentally use the right locations in the texture-only test just because the locations are different in that test.

Comment: this is how i set the texture uniforms : 
`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);`
`glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "texture1"), 0); // 0 -> GL_TEXTURE0`
`glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "texture2"), 1);`
`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1ID);`
`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);`
`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2ID);`
I get tex1ID and tex2ID as returned by a function that loads texture from file.

Comment: What if `FragColor = vec4(texColor + 0.00001f*RefractedFragColor, 1.0);`? or perhaps `FragColor = vec4(texColor, 1.0f - 0.00001f*RefractedFragColor.r);` ? This way, the difference should be imperceptible, but RefractedFragColor is not unused.

Comment: `FragColor = vec4(texColor+ 0.0f * RefractedFragColor, 1.0);` - this gives me the texture, similar to the second image in question. 
`FragColor = vec4(texColor+ 0.1f * RefractedFragColor, 1.0);` - this does not work.

Comment: Another possibility is that RefractedFragColor is NaN, but this is seemingly ruled out by the constTexColor experiment. Another idea: Does anything change if you change the order in which the uniforms are declared? Another idea: What if you bind a completely white texture to texture1? Another idea: What if you do the `+0.0f*RefractedFragColor` but the 0.0f is a uniform set to 0.0f instead of just the number 0.0f?

Comment: changing order of declaring uniforms did not work. 
I added a white texture instead of the current one i use.  - https://ibb.co/Xzb8S3P
Changing the value to a uniform :
`uniform float ratio;`
`FragColor = vec4(texColor+ ratio * RefractedFragColor, 1.0);`
and `shader.setFloat("ratio", 0.0f);`
weirdly did not work. while using the constant 0.0f still works

Comment: I mean if you try to do the mixed refraction+texture, but the texture is completely white, so it should give the same results as the refraction+constTexColor test.

Comment: Another thought: are you sure the texture coordinates are correct? You could do something like `FragColor=vec4(texCoord,0.5f,1.0f);` to check

Comment: `FragColor=vec4(texCoord,0.5f,1.0f);` gives me this : https://ibb.co/ZNJcHBh
what does that mean?

Comment: Looks like your texture coordinates are okay (I am surprised you did not know that). Now that I think about it, we already knew they were okay, because the texture worked. I don't have any more ideas of things to check.

Comment: I created the model in blender, but i did not do uv mapping. I am not worried about mapping correctly, but to get the effect i want with refraction. I am kind of new to opengl. I am most confused about how it works with a constant value, but fails when it comes from a texture. Its still the same type of value

Comment: a general troubleshooting procedure is to keep deleting stuff until the stuff that's not deleted works properly. Then, add stuff back in. This usually helps you figure out which part is broken.

Comment: alright, i have to figure it out that way , thank you